# Zip doesn't create a correct key-value pairs in dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, zip

I was doing leetcode 20. Valid Parentheses problem, and found this weird occurrence. I am using zip to create a dict and map key value pairs consisting of braces as chars. And on some iterations, keys from one list don't match values on the other list, which is weird. I didn't found the answer to why is this happening.

So, because they don't always match, the answer is sometimes wrong.

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        # {([])}()[]{}{[()]}
        opened_ls = []
        open_braces_set = {'{', '[', '('}
        close_braces_set = {'}', ']', ')'}
        d = dict(zip(open_braces_set, close_braces_set))

        for symb in s:
            if symb in open_braces_set:
                opened_ls.append(symb)
            else:
                try:
                    if d[opened_ls.pop()] != symb:
                        return False
                except Exception:
                    # if close bracet and no opened
                    return False
        # if there are unclosed braces
        if opened_ls:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I am expecting so `dict(zip(list1, list2))` always should result in `{list1_val: list2_val, list1_val: list2: val}` etc

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've just figured it out, that is because I used sets, and they are unordered. Took me an hour of my time, and I realized it right after I posted a question. Rubber duck debugging I guess